# Proof of Faà di Bruno formula

Tags: combinatorics, derivatives, summation

By induction, I want to prove the Faà di Bruno formula for $n$-times differentiable $f,g$
\begin{align*}
        D^n(f\circ g) = \sum_{(k_1,\ldots,k_n)\in T_n} \frac{n!}{k_1!\cdots k_n!} \Big(\big(D^{k_1+\ldots+k_n} f\big) \circ g\Big) \prod_{\substack{m=1\\k_m\geq 1}}^n \bigg( \frac{D^m g}{m!}\bigg)^{k_m},
    \end{align*}
where $T_n := \big\{k\in \mathbb{N}_0^n : \sum_{j=1}^n j k_j = n\big\}$.

Induction step:
\begin{align*}
            D^n (f\circ g) &= D D^{n-1} (f\circ g) \\
            &= D \Bigg( \sum_{(k_1,\ldots,k_{n-1})\in T_{n-1}} \frac{(n-1)!}{k_1!\cdots k_{n-1}!} \Big(\big(D^{k_1+\ldots+k_{n-1}} f\big) \circ g\Big) \prod_{\substack{m=1\\k_m\geq 1}}^{n-1} \bigg( \frac{D^m g}{m!}\bigg)^{k_m}\Bigg)\\
            &= \sum_{(k_1,\ldots,k_{n-1})\in T_{n-1}} \frac{(n-1)!}{k_1!\cdots k_{n-1}!} D\Bigg( \Big(\big(D^{k_1+\ldots+k_{n-1}} f\big) \circ g\Big) \prod_{\substack{m=1\\k_m\geq 1}}^{n-1} \bigg( \frac{D^m g}{m!}\bigg)^{k_m}\Bigg)\\
            &= \sum_{(k_1,\ldots,k_{n-1})\in T_{n-1}} \frac{(n-1)!}{k_1!\cdots k_{n-1}!} \Bigg( \Big(\big(D^{k_1+\ldots+k_{n-1}+1} f\big) \circ g\Big) Dg \prod_{\substack{m=1\\k_m\geq 1}}^{n-1} \bigg( \frac{D^m g}{m!}\bigg)^{k_m} \\
            &\hspace{0.5cm}+ \Big(\big(D^{k_1+\ldots+k_{n-1}} f\big) \circ g\Big) \sum_{\substack{j=1\\k_j\geq 1}}^{n-1} k_j \bigg(\frac{D^j g}{j!}\bigg)^{k_j-1} \frac{D^{j+1} g}{j!} \prod_{\substack{m=1\\m\neq j\\k_m\geq 1}}^{n-1} \bigg( \frac{D^m g}{m!}\bigg)^{k_m}\Bigg)\\
            &= \Bigg(\sum_{(k_1,\ldots,k_{n-1})\in T_{n-1}} \frac{(n-1)!}{k_1!\cdots k_{n-1}!} \Bigg( \Big(\big(D^{k_1+\ldots+k_{n-1}+1} f\big) \circ g\Big) Dg \prod_{\substack{m=1\\k_m\geq 1}}^{n-1} \bigg( \frac{D^m g}{m!}\bigg)^{k_m}\Bigg)\Bigg) \\
            &\hspace{0.5cm}+ \Bigg(\sum_{(k_1,\ldots,k_{n-1})\in T_{n-1}} \frac{(n-1)!}{k_1!\cdots k_{n-1}!} \Bigg(\Big(\big(D^{k_1+\ldots+k_{n-1}} f\big) \circ g\Big) \sum_{\substack{j=1\\k_j\geq 1}}^{n-1} k_j \bigg(\frac{D^j g}{j!}\bigg)^{k_j-1} \frac{D^{j+1} g}{j!} \prod_{\substack{m=1\\m\neq j\\k_m\geq 1}}^{n-1} \bigg( \frac{D^m g}{m!}\bigg)^{k_m}\Bigg)\Bigg)\\
            &= \Bigg(\sum_{(k_1,\ldots,k_{n})\in (T_{n-1},0)} \frac{(n-1)!}{k_1!\cdots k_{n-1}!} \Bigg( \Big(\big(D^{k_1+1+\ldots+k_{n-1}} f\big) \circ g\Big) \bigg(\frac{D^1g}{1!}\bigg)^{k_1+1} \prod_{\substack{m=2\\k_m\geq 1}}^{n} \bigg( \frac{D^m g}{m!}\bigg)^{k_m}\Bigg)\Bigg) \\
            &\hspace{0.5cm}+ \Bigg(\sum_{(k_1,\ldots,k_{n-1})\in T_{n-1}} \frac{(n-1)!}{k_1!\cdots k_{n-1}!} \Bigg(\Big(\big(D^{k_1+\ldots+k_{n-1}} f\big) \circ g\Big) \sum_{\substack{j=1\\k_j\geq 1}}^{n-1} k_j \bigg(\frac{D^j g}{j!}\bigg)^{k_j-1} \frac{D^{j+1} g}{j!} \prod_{\substack{m=1\\m\neq j\\k_m\geq 1}}^{n-1} \bigg( \frac{D^m g}{m!}\bigg)^{k_m}\Bigg)\Bigg)\\
        \end{align*}
I don't know how to split $T_n$ so that I arrive at the correct sum, has anybody an idea?